The Jacobian and the normal vectors concept?
the Jacobian is basically a matrix that contains the information about the linear approximation of a scalar function at each row and it contains the change of the vector function in a specified direction according to the input in each column ,right ?(if I understand correctly)
if I take a row vector and multiply it with the dx vector i get the change in the scalar function because of the changes in each input and, but if I look at the row vector itself can I think of it as a normal to the linear approximation at the given point ?
as for ds as a vector  I am uncertain to what It means  I try to think of the partial derivative of each column as a basis of the new space so the normal to them is normal to the space , I can understand this partially for vectors in $ R^3$ but higher than that lower than  I get confused is ,what is the ds vector in surface internals , and does it hold a mathematical meaning for higher dimensions ?

The Jacobian is the linear approximation of an n-dimensional map of coordinates
$$\begin{align}&(x_1(y_1 +dx_1,\dots ,y_n+dy_n), \dots x_n(y_1+dy_1,\dots , y_n+dy_n)) \ = \   
\\& (x_1(y_1,\dots ,y_n), \dots , x_n(y_1,\dots , y_n)) \\& \ + \ \sum_i dy_i\ \partial_{y_i} \  (x_1(y_1,\dots ,y_n), \dots x_n(y_1,\dots , y_n))  + o(|x-x_0|^2)   \end{align}$$
No vectors, only coordinate lists $\mathbf X=(x1,\dots, x_n) $ implied.
Of course one may define $$t_i = \partial_{y_i} x $$  as the tangent vector at a point in the direction of the new coordinate. But its a map between different spaces and as such it makes not much sense to consider the entrances of the Jacobian as vectors: their values depend on a pair of bases.

maybe the problem is that I am viewing this based on my linear alegrba knowledge I considered the Jacobin as a linear transformation matrix and since it is finite I considered the column and row space while thinking of each column as a  vector, we did not really learn the concept map but from your explanation ,  is every linear transformation from a space to another a map ? and I should not think of the entries of it  as vector since they depend on the basis of both vector spaces and there meaning only translates when operating the matrix on a vector ? (maybe I should ask what is a map )
